# Why removing working answer that their owner haven't wrote an explanation/added any ref (just commands)

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

This question:

[Comand: "unity-control-center background" not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489560/comand-unity-control-center-background-not-working)

got an answer, simply just this:

> unity-control-center appearance

Well, it works perfectly. I've tested it and I voted it up. When I came back to edit it. Ooops gone!

I agree that it should be flagged as low quality, But I do not with removing it. Now, the question has no answer and any one comes later cannot know that there was a working solution.

I think it will be helpful if it is left as a comment at least. Or could we have some thing like HOLD period similar to questions.

Comment: you could edit in more information to save answers like that... anyway just a command is never a good answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's been undeleted in the mean time but the 'answer' is still there. It's a horrible answer though. No explanation, no nothing.

Comment: @terdon yep it's back :).

Comment: @Mateo, just a command, it could be even harmful without explanations. But like I lost a helpful hint

Comment: now that is better, it shows why, and how to verify.

Comment: @mateo, I just want if we can get larger time slot before it is deleted. Low Quality Posts queue too quick & there is no hold  period. This pushing me get different behavior, to be evil :), Clone it or let's say Steal it, add more explanation, flag that dummy answer to be deleted :D collect my bonus!

Comment: Sure, this is "the best answer rises to the top" lazy answers like "here's the link" "run command:"(with no explanation) or "the first hit on google answers", even if they are *technically* correct aren't going very far. I have seen may situations where several people essentially have the same commands - except one person formats it, adds more information, and has links to back it up, and maybe even pictures, that gets my upvote. plus I have seen more harm come from short half answers, that don't explain the process of doing something to a new user.

Comment: @Mateo so your are saying that the FGITW doesn't exist in AU?! O_O

Comment: @Braiam nope, it still happens ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had a problem like that with a really trite answer, I might comment that the OP should add details and that if they didn't, I might.

That being a given, I don't think people with delete votes or that use downvotes a lot would downvote or vote to delete an answer with that sort of comment.